# swiftui Textfield moves cursor to end with each change

Tags: swiftui, textfield

If I pass a binding to the TextField then whenever you edit the centre of the text the cursor will jump to the end of the line after each character insert.
This only occurs on an actual device (iPadOS). The simulator does not display this behaviour.
My work around is to create a state variable that I set onAppear with the value from the binding and copy onEditingChanged. I then pass this state variable to the TextField instead of the binding variable directly. This breaks the one source of truth.

Does anyone have a better solution.

- Swift 5
- iOS 14.7
- XCODE 13 Beta Aug 10

```
struct infoSheetView: View {
   
    @Binding var cameraURL: String

    @State var tmpCameraURL: String = ""
 
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            Form{
                Section(header: Text("Camera").font(.title)) {
                    TextField("Camera URL", text: $tmpCameraURL, onEditingChanged:  {_ in
                        cameraURL = tmpCameraURL
                    }).autocapitalization(.none).disableAutocorrection(true)
                        
           
            }
        }.frame(width:400,height:390)
        
        .onAppear() {
            tmpCameraURL = cameraURL
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: can you reproduce it with xcode 12? This sounds like you're modifying your `cameraURL` somewhere on changes

Comment: Thanks for your tip. Exact same problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Testing on iPhone 14 Pro running 17.3. Xcode 15.2, Swift 5. I changed the target minimum deployment to iOS 14.7... but I couldn't test on a device running 14.7.

The following code seems to work for me. No jumping to the end of the text field if I place the cursor in the middle and edit the text. And the ContentView text is updated when I return to ContentView after editing on NewView.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var someText: String = "A string"
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            VStack {
                Text(someText)
                
                NavigationLink(destination: NewView(someText: $someText)) {
                    Label("Goto NewView", systemImage: "globe")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct NewView: View {
    @Binding var someText: String

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Form {
                Section(header: Text("Camera").font(.title)) {
                    TextField("Camera Field", text: $someText)
                        .autocapitalization(.none)
                        .autocorrectionDisabled()
                }
            }
            .frame(width: 400, height: 390)
        }
    }
}
```